# ChromeDriver gives 'Disable Developer Extensions' popup

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried every possible solution on SO that I can find and no luck.  Most answers are a few years old.  I am having the issue with ChromeDriver v26.14, Webdriver v 3.1 running tests on Selenium v3.0 and using MS TestRunner from VS2015.  And my version of Chrome is 56.0.

Does anyone have any more recent solutions?

Comment: Are you sure you have the latest ChromeDriver? your version doesn't make sense, latest is 2.27 and is compatible with Chrome 56

Comment: According to NuGet the version I have is 26.14.313457.1 it is listed as WebDriver.ChromeDriver by selenium.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is with the outdated NuGet package you're using. Try uninstalling yours and installing Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver:

From "Manage NuGet Packages" uninstall `WebDriver.ChromeDriver` and install `Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver`.

Comment: I have updated and now have Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver v2.28.0, Selenium.Support v2.53.1, Selenium.WebDriver v2.53.1 Chrome v56.9.292487 and I am still getting the popup.  I am also using the following chromeoptions...  'var chromeoptions = new ChromeOptions();
                    chromeoptions.AddArguments("start-maximized");
                    chromeoptions.AddArguments("chrome.switches", "--disable-extensions", "--disable-extensions-file-access-check", "--test-type");'

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help but try updating Selenium to the latest version 3.+ and verify your using latest chrome driver I think 2.28 currently.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upgrade Selenium to the newest version as version 2.53.1 is our current level for the grid where these tests will be running.  These tests must work with that version.